# Organizing code into methods?

Tags: java

Question about organizing code for readability, unit tests and stacks.  I have read comments regarding not to creating too many methods just for organzing code. At the same time I also read comments to break down code into different method for unit tests.  What is the rules of thumbs?  Take the following for example, should each numbered point break into different method or all should be in one giant method with many many lines :

```
@Path("login/partners/{partner-id}")
@GET
public void login(
    @Context final HttpServletRequest request,
    @Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse,
    @PathParam("partner-id") final String partnerId,
    @CookieParam(CookieEnum.Constants.SSO_LOGIN_COOKIE_NAME) final String loginCookie,
    @HeaderParam(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT) final String userAgent)
  throws ServletException, IOException {

    //1. error checking for request
    //2. fetch data from database
    //3. checking data from database
    //4. set session variables
    //5. response

}
```

Comment: What is stack in that context?

Comment: creating more methods means adding to the stack?

Comment: Ok, you mean call stack. Wasn't totally clear, because it's whole different level of abstraction.

Comment: I will recommend you to read SOLID principle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 of the rules of thumbs

1) if the block of code can be reused by other method(not necessary now but in future).. then put the block of code in a method.

2) long lines with different tasks should be broken into methods so as to reduce the complexity of the method.-->easier to understand + easier to debug + easier for unit testing

Comment: Christopher, I am under the same impression. But in same cases, block of code not reusable but long.  So, split into different method is easier to read, debug and all. Then i read comments that is not recommended as it is adding up stacks.

Comment: @TestMirror don't believe those who claim that many methods hurt performance. Don't sacrifice readability and maintainability to make imaginary performance gains. Computers are extremely fast, the JIT inlines short methods and does all sorts of optimizations for you, and performance problems are almost always caused by bad algorithms, or IO. Not by one or two additional method calls. Premature optimization is the root of all evil. If they criticize your code over performance, ask them to prove, with measurements, that their code is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some points about using method:

*If you use the same block of code more than one time, make a method out of him, so if it to be modified, you only do it in one place.

*Each method should have only one responsibility, easier  to debug, test and its simply cleaner.

*Code readability - give a method a meaningful name, don't be afraid using long 
names for that matter as it can be used for self documentation.

Comment: I take it as if for readability, unit tests purposes, even if the method is not reusable, as long as it is single responsibility, improve readability, it can be moved out, even if more methods are created in this class.